# Extend PowerShell Custom Type by Adding a NoteProperty with Value of System.Boolean = $false using ps1xml

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-module

I am trying to extend the type of a custom object using a custom types.ps1xml file. The file works and extends many types the way I want.

I have been able to extend a custom type with a NoteProperty which has a boolean value of $true.  All I want to be able to do now is add a NoteProperty to a different type with a TypeName value of System.Boolean and a Value of $false. My problem is that the `<value>` property is always interpreted as a string and when cast as a TypeName of System.Boolean, it ALWAYS returns $true, because any non zero-length string returns $true.

I'm typing this on my phone and in a hurry to get back to work, but the pertinent parts of the ps1xml file are:

```
<Type>
  <Name>My.Custom.Object</Name>
  <Members>
    <NoteProperty>
      <Name>PSIsContainer</Name>
      <TypeName>System.Boolean<TypeName>
      <Value>True</Value>
    </NoteProperty>
  </Members>
</Type>
```

That correctly results in a NoteProperty that reflects a Boolean value of $true. However, if I change the value to false, or 0, or null, or '', or "", or $false, or [bool]0, or any other feasible value with or without quotes or with or without $ or inside of $() or with escaped quotes or characters; it ALWAYS returns as a Boolean value of $true. If I leave `<Value>` blank it gives me an error when loading the xml, so that doesn't work either. If I change the `<TypeName>` to something else, like a System.IO.File or whatever, it actually converts the value of "false" to a file object named "false", or to whatever type I identify in the `<TypeName>`. So clearly it works as intended, except I cannot assign a bool value of $false. No matter what I do. If I leave `<TypeName>` out altogether it defaults to a System.String and that doesn't help me.

If you look at Get-Member for a file or directory you will see the corresponding NoteProperty of PSIsContainer equal to a System.Boolean value of $true or $false, depending; and my output when set to true is exactly the same as the default directory object. That suggests it should be possible to set a NoteProperty to $false.

I almost forgot, but in fact, I am able to add a NoteProperty using Add-Member and set the value properly to $false, but for my script/tool to work, I need all instances of this object to have this NoteProperty and so going with the types.ps1xml file is the only way I can think of to do that.

Mind you, the object I'm setting this property on is a custom object that doesn't have any conflicting or existing property with that name or value. And it doesn't matter if I change the `<Name>` to something else, like "IsAwesome"; it still doesn't work for $false. I tried searching in the existing types.ps1xml and format.ps1xml and there is no hint at how they do it. I've searched online extensively for days, and even looked at some textbooks on Powershell to no avail.

Can someone please help me!?

Comment: `Update-TypeData -TypeName My.Custom.Object -MemberType NoteProperty -MemberName PSIsContainer -Value $false`

Comment: @PetSerAl I will try that first thing in the morning. Although I'd like to know how, if it's at all possible, to do this in the config file, but if this works I will be pretty happy nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's possible. I've used [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to look into `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility` assembly, where `UpdateTypeDataCommand` cmdlet resides. It seems to me that it uses `ProcessNote` method from `Runspaces.TypeTable` to add Note Properties. Here is the relevant part from it:

```
// System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.TypeTable
private static void ProcessNote(
    LoadContext context,
    string typeName,
    Node node,
    PSMemberInfoInternalCollection<PSMemberInfo> membersCollection,
    Collection<int> nodeLineNumbers
)
{

...

if (actualNodes.Count == 1)
{
    if (actualNodes[0].nodeError)
    {
        return;
    }
    Type typeFromString = TypeTable.GetTypeFromString(
        context,
        typeName,
        actualNodes[0]
    );
    if (typeFromString == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        obj = LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(
            obj,
            typeFromString,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        );
    }
    catch (PSInvalidCastException ex)
    {
        context.AddError(typeName,
            actualNodes[0].lineNumber,
            TypesXmlStrings.Exception,
            new object[] {ex.Message}
        );
        return;
    }
}

PSNoteProperty pSNoteProperty = new PSNoteProperty(node2.innerText, obj);
pSNoteProperty.isHidden = (node.isHidden.HasValue && node.isHidden.Value);
TypeTable.AddMember(context,
    typeName,
    node.lineNumber,
    pSNoteProperty,
    membersCollection, 
    nodeLineNumbers
);
```

If you specify `<TypeName>` in XML, it tries to convert NoteProperty's value to it. And since the original value is a string, it loolks like this method is called:

```
// System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives
private static bool ConvertStringToBool(
    object valueToConvert,
    Type resultType,
    bool recursion,
    PSObject originalValueToConvert,
    IFormatProvider formatProvider,
    TypeTable backupTable
)
{
    LanguagePrimitives.typeConversion.WriteLine(
        "Converting string to boolean.",
        new object[0]
    );
    return LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue((string)valueToConvert);
}
```

And `LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue` method's body is sadly simple:

```
// System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives
internal static bool IsTrue(string s)
{
    return s.Length != 0;
}
```

If the string is not empty it's converted to `true`. And since you can't have empty `<Value>` node in XML (`Update-TypeData : Error: The node Value is not allowed.`) this effectively makes it impossible to create a NoteProperty with `false` boolean value.

P.S. While it corresponds to observerd behaviour, it's still mostly guesswork, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just realized I never thanked you for this answer. Even though it didn't solve my problem, I believe your answer is 100% accurate in that you cannot use the custom type xml file to do what I wanted. It's a shame, and a seemingly large lack of foresight on MSFTs part. Thank you for the enlightening information though.